# Jmeter - Cannot invoke "org.apache.jmeter.gui.JMeterGUIComponent.clearGui()" because "guicomp" is null

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to migrate to Jmeter 5.5

I have a script that works perfectly fine on Jmeter 5.4.3, but when I try to load it on JM 5.5 I got:

[image]

-Version 5.5 is just downloaded
-The plugins that I am using in /lib folder are (C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\lib\ext) are:

jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.4.jar

jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar

How to solve this issue with JM5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot help you without seeing:

1. At least schematic view of your Test Plan

   [image]
2. [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file (preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for all `org.apache.jmeter` components)

   [image]

Instead of installing the plugins manually just drop the latest version of [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/) to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation and restart JMeter to pick it up.

One done when you will try to open the test plan which uses any of [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) known to the plugins manager you will be prop

Comment: thanks Dmitri. this line actually helped me. "Instead of installing the plugins manually just drop the latest version of JMeter Plugins Manager to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation and restart JMeter to pick it up."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I had to add the DBMon Sample Collector plugin, and it solved the problem.